# Less metallic from a distance

Tags: materials, reflection

I have a large plane with spots that are metallic. It's made with a simple noise textures and colorramp.

But far in the distance, when the sun is low, it's making some weird flickering reflections when the camera move.
Is there a way to make it render it less metallic when it's far away from the camera? So the distant part of the plane doesn't make any reflections?

Comment: you could use a driver - distance from object to camera and drive the metallic value with it

Comment: How do you mean driver? I haven't heard of a driver before.

Comment: maybe watch some beginner tutorials like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8GR9icb51w Essentially drivers change a property (like location, scale or whatever) depending on another property. They are very powerful and if you don't use them, you will miss a lot you can do. E.g. you can move a box automatically on the x axis if you rotate a cylinder on the y axis.

Comment: I have looked at it and you are right, it can be very useful :)
However, in this case I can get it to control the metallic by the distance of the camera, but since the camera is moving over the plane, and therefore always the same distance between the plane and the camera.
And if I make it the distance between some empty in the distance and the camera, it affects the metallic on the whole plane, also right infront of the camera, and not only in the distance.

Comment: Could you control the metallic based on the Light Path ‘Ray Length’? -  ie, reduce metallic to zero as the ray length gets high.

Comment: You could try despeckle in the compositor, but it might not work for this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly then this should help - you can use the Ray Length to control the properties of your surface.

Consider the following nodes :

[image: nodes]

Here the Map Range is used to convert the range of ray lengths (in this case 35-> 48) to a range of Metallicness (1 -> 0) - so anything below 35 will be 100% metallic, anything above 48 will be 0% metallic and anything inbetween will vary between the two.

This produces the following result (with the world the default forest texture) :

[image: result]

Note that close to the camera the plane is reflective (due to being metallic) while away from the camera it's only diffuse (non-metallic). As the camera moves the region of metallic will follow.

This works as the camera ray is projected to the surface and its ray length represents the distance to/from the camera and this is being used to control the properties of the surface.

You can simply adjust the values of the Map Range node to vary the distance, sharpness of the transition (using the 'From' range) and the amount of 'metallic' (the 'To' range). You could pass the output of the Map Range through a Color Ramp to give more control if wanted more control over the transition.

Comment: thanks a lot :) that worked...